# React show page when images are loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The past two nights I have been struggling with an issue in React. I have a website that has multiple images (a header, some gallery images, some cool photos). I want the page to render in whole the moment all images are correctly loaded.

There are people that tell me to use the lifecycle hooks, but that doesn't seem to work because the render proces is faster than the time some images need to load in.

This one time I thought I managed to get it working by doing the following: Add inline styling to container div saying display none. Then add onLoad={method to trigger a display: inherit} to the container div.

But when I used a bigger image (of 15MB, just to test it out) the loading was perhaps a succes but still took time to show on the page. So it didn't work afterall. It just 'looked' like it worked cause the other image loaded faster.

Anyone has any other idea's to tackle this problem?

Best of wishes,

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to defer the page load unless all your images are downloaded by the browser and are ready to render?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but basically. Yes and no. I want the page to show as a whole. So instead of seeing different images pop up, I would like to insert something like a loading-icon. But the moment the loading icon dissapears, the whol page should just instantly be there with images and all.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of images you have on the page you can do a counter that starts from zero and put an onLoad on each image which adds one to the counter when the image is loaded...then do a condition:

```
 {counter===numberOfImages? <Content><Content/> : null}
```

Comment: That's actualy not a bad method of handling this. Do you think this will also take care of after-download rendering? Cause I used an onload on images but they still 'popped' because they still needed to be rendered

Comment: well of course they are going to pop...you can't expect nothing to be on the page until the images are loaded and then everything pop all of a sudden...but..without popping.. :D

Comment: just try it out and see how it goes